# Matrix Multiplication of large data in Hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, matrix, mapreduce, hdfs

Am I able to multiply 2 matrices of large size if matrices is not labeled like  [this](http://magpiehall.com/one-step-matrix-multiplication-with-hadoop/) ?

Matrix A few records:

```
1,3,4,5
6,1,8,0
```

Matrix B

```
1,4 
5,6
2,5
4,5
```

Hope once if I store the matrix in HDFS with block size 128 MB and my file size is about 200 MB. 2 maps get executed and if I multiply those 2 matrices. we cannot make sure the result will be correct becoz the oredering may change as map takes different input split. But If we are doing it for file size of 100 MB this issue will not happen.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you plan not to use the representation shown in that example, how would you put both matrices in one file and find boundary between them in the program?

Comment: That doesnt matter we can make use of multipleInputs and do operations in reducer. In reducer we get the same format like what we get the reducer values from that link. we can make our both mappers to perform so

Comment: @PonMaran: But I need to make sure if I mentioned issue is correct. And is there any way of doing multiplication for large data

Comment: Unless input format from [here][1] used, I believe you need to process each matrix in single mapper, so that you know the element index - row number to be tracked with a counter and column number being the array index.


  [1]: http://magpiehall.com/one-step-matrix-multiplication-with-hadoop/

Comment: yes.The same happens for matrix vector operation aswell right? [link](http://magpiehall.com/matrix-vector-multiplication-with-mapreduce/)

Answer (score 0):

you should know their indexes.
or if you already know the elements do it manually like :

1*1 + 3*5 + 4*2 + 5*4
6*4 + 1*6 + 8*5 + 0*5